# Granting all users access to mounted CIFS shares

Tags: debian, permissions, filesystems, cifs

I'm trying to set up a debian server that will run several network-based services. These services need access to an external network drive to store their data. For security reasons, I have set up each service to run under it's own user. To allow them all to access the network share, I created a new group, `driveaccess`, with gip 1003

I then set up the network share by adding the following to /ets/fstab

```
//192.168.42.2/Data/ /media/Data cifs guest,rw,mand,gid=1003,forcegid,user=duckies%swordfish 0 0
```

After mounting the drive, the service accounts see the premissions as

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root driveaccess   1544704 Jun  1  2013 AppData1.dat
```

And the processes can read the data with no problems, but any attempt to write to the drive fails

```
touch: cannot touch `test.txt': Permission denied
```

What do I need to add to the fstab to let everything in the driveaccess group write to the share?

I already executed:

```
usermod -aG driveaccess serviceaccount1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably want to add explicit permissions to the mounted file system in the `fstab` entry:

```
<your other options>,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770
```

This will be on the safe side by allowing all group members to read, write and execute all files and prohibiting access to any *other* user of the system. If you still want read access for the *others* you will have to replace the `0` by an appropriate value. e.g.

```
<your other options>,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775
```

for read and execute rights.

Comment: Is this supposed to work on Mac too? I get `mount_smbfs: -o file_mode: option not supported`

Answer (score 1):

In my case with Win 10, besides the permissions in gnu/linux side

```
 sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user1,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.1.11/shared-d ~/shared-d
```

I had to add permission to "everyone" for read/write in Windows side: properties -> sharing -> share...

Comment: Share permissions should almost always be set to give "Everyone" full access. From there you can use standard file permissions to restrict access as necessary.